# Browser reads longitude variable as undefined

Tags: javascript, api, geolocation

I have the variables 'lat' and 'long' at the end of the api. However, the browser console only gives the information from the 'lat' variable. It logs the 'long' variable as undefined.

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=> {
  let long;
  let lat;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      long = position.coords.longitutde;



      const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
      const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/8c09bdf7710c871187bd30800c10c0aa/${lat},${long}`;

    fetch(api)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });

    });
  }
});
```

It should log my current coordinates to the console. However, I keep getting this error message:

script.js:15 GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/8c09bdf7710c871187bd30800c10c0aa/38.2050304,undefined 400 (Bad Request)

38.2050304 is my latitude.

Comment: spell mistake `position.coords.longitutde;`. It should be `position.coords.longitude`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake in `position.coords.longitutde;`.

```
long = position.coords.longitude;
```